# Reads the Value from zval* in separate thread - PHP extension c++

Tags: php, c++, centos7, php-internals

I am using **Centos 7** (**PHP - 5.6.36** Thread safety - disabled) i have created **PHP** extension in **c++** to store the function call stack traces.

Storing the information starts from `PHP_RINIT_FUNCTION` and end in `PHP_RSHUTDOWN_FUNCTION`.

Here, I have used persistent memory allocation to store the values,finally the result will be stored in the fomrat of zval* can able parse it. 
I was push it into the `vector(m_resultVect)` of every request shutdown method `called(PHP_RSHUTDOWN_FUNCTION)`.
In another thread i am swapping the `vector (m_resultVect)` to some other and then tried to parse the zval* to get call stack traces info.
But I can't access the zval*.

why I can't able to access in another thread?
is it gets cleared automatically by zendMM?

.

Comment: Maybe it would help to show the code you are talking about. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What kind of vectors are you talking about? Do you mean `std::vector`?

Comment: @Gerhardh yuh..it's std::vector

Comment: Then this is not related to C at all. Please take a few seconds to think twice which tags to add. The wrong tag was already removed.